# Why does an inline-block div get positioned lower when it has content?

Tags: css

If you have three identical divs positioned inline-block they are aligned perfectly. But if you put any content in any of the divs it drops down below the others. Why does it do that?

```
<div class="left">?</div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="right"></div>

div {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-:2px;
    height:100px;
    width:25px;
    border:1px solid black;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7kkC6/

better example: http://jsfiddle.net/7kkC6/9/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is because vertical-align is by default set to baseline.
You can fix your problem by setting it to top :

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-:2px;
    height:100px;
    width:25px;
    border:1px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
}​
```

The demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/7kkC6/4/

Comment: i didn't even know vertical-align was in play here.